# how to find layout folder for Main_activity.xml in hedgehog version of android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

- I am not able to find layout folder in res folder.
- I want to start my career in app dev but can't able to do layout.
- I have tried to design the layout of my app.
- Please help me.
- I am sharing the screenshot of the same[here is what it showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYcEY.png)

## i have tried to find Main_activity.xml so that i can design layout for my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your application using Jetpack Compose, with it you don't need `.xml` files for layout, because the UI is written in Kotlin.

You can read more about Jetpack Compose here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial

Comment: Or you can still use views.  Create an Empty View Activity when you choose your project type, or just create a new layout file and name it whatever you want (the name isn't important).  Both approaches have pluses and minuses.